Deserialize null property as default
Having a json like this:
[{"Familiy":"A","Article":null}, {"Familiy":"B","Article":"plant"}]

I'm trying to deserialize it into a ObservableCollection< ArticleModel >, being ArticleModel the following class:
public class ArticleModel
{
    public String Familiy { get; set; }
    public String Article { get; set; }
}

The deserialization process is done the following way:
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
};

 ObservableCollection<ArticleModel> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ArticleModel>>(jsonString, settings);

The problem is sometimes the Article coming as null from the external WS, which is causing some UI bindings fail later on. I would like to automatically set Article to default string in case it comes null from WS.
So far I have tried the follwing approaches:

Specify Article property default value using [DefaultValue("")] and ignore null values using JsonSerializerSettings
Not specifying Article property default value but providing a default constructor to ArticleModel and ignore null values using JsonSerializerSettings

The result is the same. Artcile is null.
I also tried this answer, which implies using System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft, with the same result as before.

You need to set the default value like this:
public class ArticleModel
{
    public string Familiy { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; } = "No Article";
}

Already tested and works:

